# Error while using django_countries module

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model as below

```
class Person1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20,null = True)
    country = CountryField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

while I'm trying to add value to the model fields it is showing the error
`AttributeError: 'BlankChoiceIterator' object has no attribute '__len__'`

Is there any issue with new version of django

Problem is occurring while adding value from admin page

Comment: _while I'm trying to add value to the model fields_ Show the actual code where this happens.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried to add value from admin page, but I can't access the adding page. It is showing error there

Comment: Please, provide the whole traceback/error and the code that produces the error.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych There is no code that producing error. I tried to add value through admin page. But I can't even access the adding page, error is showing there in browser

Comment: Package does not support Django 5.0 yet https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/issues/447

Comment: I guess iklinac answered your question. But for the future, errors don't come from nowhere, if you get the error, there's code that produces it. It might not be your code, but some package's code that you use. That's why it's always important to include the whole traceback, so we know where it comes from.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych This is the only code I have. I'm just trying that module

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Error is coming from the code inside the module

Answer (score 0):

[django-countries package](https://pypi.org/project/django-countries/) does not currently support Django 5.

However, there is a [suggested monkey patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/35046#comment:4) in settings.py although this hasn't been thoroughly tested. In your settings.py use:

```
from django_countries.widgets import LazyChoicesMixin

LazyChoicesMixin.get_choices = lambda self: self._choices
LazyChoicesMixin.choices = property(LazyChoicesMixin.get_choices, LazyChoicesMixin.set_choices)
```

The monkey patch is the workaround until the update is released.